# testrpc throwing 'out of gas' if same number of parameters passed while deploying as constructor

Tags: testrpc, out-of-gas

When I'm trying to deploy my contract on testrpc with correct parameters, it's throwing 'VM Exception while processing transaction: out of gas' exception. I deployed same [contract](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0xe7081aede253f3d3adefd49cd4903f962ea76978867f6257a1df40071abbc124) on Ropsten and it worked fine.

```
/** Constructor */
    function Hotel(
            bytes32 _name,
            string _description,
            bytes16 _locationLatitude,
            bytes16 _locationLongitude,
            int _hotelTimeZone
        ) {
            name = _name;
            description = _description;
            locationLatitude = _locationLatitude;
            locationLongitude = _locationLongitude;
            timezone = _hotelTimeZone;
            owner = msg.sender;
        }
```

I'm deploying like given below on testrpc and it fails.

```
deployer.deploy(Hotel, 'Hotel', 'ABCDEF', '10.1231', '77.5946', 19800, {gas: 17000000});
```

But if I remove or add an extra parameter it works.

```
deployer.deploy(Hotel, 'Hotel', 'ABCDEF', '10.1231', '77.5946', 19800, 1,
 {gas: 17000000});
 or 
deployer.deploy(Hotel, 'Hotel', 'ABCDEF', '10.1231', '77.5946' {gas: 17000000});
```

I increased the block gas size of testrpc and supplied quite an amount of gas but still, it didn't work. I even reduced the constructor parameters to just one and still it fails if I just pass one input. It works if I pass more than that or nothing at all.

Comment: What version of testrpc are you using?

Comment: Latest one 3.0.5

Comment: Not really an answer, but testrpc 4.0 was just released. If it still happens with this version i would post a bug report.

Comment: @Mayank - TestRPC maintainer here - if this is still a problem, I'd love to have an issue filed. https://github.com/ethereumjs/testrpc